# Is "to lodge a complaint" a collocation or phrasal verb?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, collocations

Is the expression "to lodge a complaint" a collocation  or phrasal verb? I think it is a phrasal verb .

Comment: I think "lodge" is a transitive verb and "a complaint" is its object !

Comment: It is a collocation, not a phrasal verb. We can submit a complaint, file a complaint, make a complaint, lodge a complaint.

Comment: Phrasal verbs are verbs + words that are normally prepositions, like *through*, *out*, *down*, *up*, *away*, etc.  Never a verb followed by a noun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Lodge a complaint' isn't a phrasal verb.

The verb lodge is not exclusively used in front of a complaint; it can also be used before a protest, grievance, claim, an appeal, etc. to imply to register  before an authority to redress it.

Answer (score 1):

"To lodge a complaint" is a set phrase. See [here](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/lodge+a+complaint).

The noun *"complaint"* is one of the nouns that may collocate with the verb *to lodge*, and the verb *"to lodge"* may collocate with the noun *complaint*. See [here](http://www.ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/complaint) and [here](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=complaint).

So "to lodge a complaint" is one of the possible collocations either of the noun "complaint" or the verb "to lodge".